# Any chance to get access to /dev/bus/usb on Android Nougat?

Tags: android, permissions, usb, android-7.0-nougat

My app is working with usb devices on android in native code using libusb, libftdi, etc. Starting Android Nougat the app is unable to read `/dev/bus/usb` for security reason.

Android Lollipop/Marshmallow device:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools asmirnov$./adb shell ls /dev/bus/usb
001
002
```

Android Nougat device:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools asmirnov$./adb shell ls /dev/bus/usb
ls: /dev/bus/usb: Permission denied
```

Is there any possibility to grant the app access like it was before?
It's highly not desired to move all usb-related code to android code from c++ code (i'm even not sure it's possible).

Comment: Run on a rooted device, presumably.

Comment: It's not desired solution obviously (but i hope it's not the only possible).